# Find the values that meet a certain criteria in a Pivot table created by Python

Tags: python, pandas

I used Python to create a table：

```
data_pivot  = pd.pivot_table(df, values='occ', 
index='ALT_grid', columns='LCT_grid', aggfunc='count')
print(data_pivot)
```

the table is similar to that in image:
[image: The figure shows the number of occurrences of an event of 90-130 kilometers corresponding to 1-24 hours. The minimum number of times in the table is 3 times]
The figure shows the number of occurrences of an event of 90-130 kilometers corresponding to 1-24 hours. The minimum number of times in the table is 3 times. 
I want to select the rows with numbers greater than 100.

My code is as follows：

> limit2 = data_pivot.values >=100
>    print(data_pivot[limit2])

However, all I get is a value greater than 100, not a whole row with values greater than 100. Just like below:

[image]
I hope that after filtering the data, all the values in any row are> 100.

The result I want is similar to the following figure, in all the rows, the value is greater than 100

[image]

I checked a lot of information, but still could not solve this problem, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your post to correctly display the images. So that it makes more sense for someone to view images and question in one place. Good Luck!

Comment: I have also edited your title and formatted some paragraphs.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was very surprised to find that in the original method I used, this problem was solved. I printed the global boolean mask and found that it met my requirements.

Comment: If you have found a solution. Please post the answer and mark it as a accepted solution as well. So that this question can be closed.